# how can I access to JSON elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how can I access to this JSON elements by javascript or JQuery and using a loop?

```
{"d":"[{\"aa\":\"11111111111111111111\",\"bb\":\"222222222222222222\"},{\"aa\":\"33333333333333333333\",\"bb\":\"444444444444444444\"}]"}
```

Comment: that's structure doesn't make much sense. Not normal to wrap an array inside quotes like that. Please be more specific about your issues and show what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mydata = {"d":"[{\"aa\":\"11111111111111111111\",\"bb\":\"222222222222222222\"},
{\"aa\":\"33333333333333333333\",\"bb\":\"444444444444444444\"}]"};

var result = mydata.d;

var objects = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

$.each(objects , function(idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.aa);
    //or you can use idx
    alert(objects[idx].aa);
    alert(objects[idx].bb);
});
```

Here is the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/1te9ojqt/

Comment: working good, but how can I access to element's value by index instead of using "obj.aa" or "obj.bb"

Comment: @Mike you can use `objects[idx]`, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through an object using a for loop

For example

```
var jsonData = {"d":"[{\"aa\":\"11111111111111111111\",\"bb\":\"222222222222222222\"},{\"aa\":\"33333333333333333333\",\"bb\":\"444444444444444444\"}]"};

for (var key in jsonData){
    console.log(jsonData[key]); //will output [{\"aa\":\"11111111111111111111\",\"bb\":\"222222222222222222\"},{\"aa\":\"33333333333333333333\",\"bb\":\"444444444444444444\"}]
    console.log(key) //will output "d"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an object inside an object. You could do

`jsonData.d = JSON.parse(jsonData.d);`

to make it's child and json object instead of a string.

You could use jQuery.each to iterate over the object.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Example

```
var jsonData = {"d":"[{\"aa\":\"11111111111111111111\",\"bb\":\"222222222222222222\"},{\"aa\":\"33333333333333333333\",\"bb\":\"444444444444444444\"}]"};

$.each(jsonData, function(key, value){
     jsonData[key] = JSON.parse(value);
});
```

This will make the object clear. If what you need is a recursi

Comment: *"It looks like you have an object inside an object."* No, the property values are *strings* containing JSON.

Comment: yes, I meant that a "wannabe object". Did you find useful the $.each method? parsing it's sons with JSON.parse?